# Access backtrace and logs in Xcode

Tags: xcode, logging, backtrace

I would like to know how I can access a backtrace in Xcode which would also include `NSLog()`s.

Comment: By "in Xcode" do you mean while debugging your app in Xcode during development? If so, then what is the issue? The logs are in the debugger console.

Comment: Yes. I want to use the backtrace to find out which API's are called when I destroy a joint in Box2D. Basically, the joint destroys perefectly on iOS but doesn't destroy when using Apportable (on an android device). This is just some way of reverse engineering a solution recommended in http://forum.apportable.com/t/box2d-revolute-joint-not-destroying/1167/4

Comment: all you have to do is insert a breakpoint and when it trips the backtrace will be in the left column (Debug navigator). you can also use the console (lldb/gdb) command `bt` while paused.

Comment: @BradAllred: thanks a lot. How can I get NSLogs included in the backtrace?

Comment: As I said, the logs are in the console. They are not associated with the stack trace.